# Modifying one object is changing value in a second object

Tags: java

```
State st = sc.que.remove();

System.out.println(st.getMoves() +" - Goal: " + Arrays.toString(st.getGoal()) + "- Puzzle: " + Arrays.toString(st.getPuzzle()));

State ss = new State(st.getPuzzle(), st.getSpace(), st.getMoves(), st.getGoal());
ss.moveUp();

System.out.println(st.getMoves() +" - Goal: " + Arrays.toString(st.getGoal()) + "- Puzzle: " + Arrays.toString(st.getPuzzle()));
```

Basically I have one state, I print off it's value. Then I create a second state using the value of the first to create an exact copy. I modify the second state using the method moveUp() which swaps a couple elements in an array withine the State. Then we I reprint the value from the first state the one that was not changed they are different.

Answer (score 1):

What are the members of `State`? If they are objects, you don't *copy* them by using `getMember()` but passing a reference to them to the second constructor. If you then call a method that changes a member of the first object, the identical member is changed in the second object, too.